# How can i get the Printer details from server using c#

Tags: c#, printing

I need to create a C# application that will run in server in that  i need to get the printer details like printer status, number of pages printed.The system which is requested for the print that systems username and system name.

If the system connected in the network requested for printing then i need to get the system details in my application

how can i do this?.

sorry for my bad English.

Comment: With the stock windows print manager you may not be able to get historical totals for things like number of pages printed. Are you looking for active jobs or historical information?

Comment: I need to get details about active jobs not historical information.  is windows print manager will help to get information in c#?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes in the .NET 3.0 System.Printing namespace are your starting point.  Beware that the amount of functionality available is pretty limited.  You can't get an event out of them that tells you that a new print job got started.  Something as simple and obvious as counting printed pages is not possible.

This is a core architectural limitation, Windows leaves a lot of the printing management up to a the printer driver.  And every printer manufacturer makes their own.  Which explains that counting pages isn't supported for example, the driver sends some kind of proprietary control command to the printer to tell it to generate copies of a document rather than Windows spooling the same document repeatedly.  That's efficient but not easily observed.  These manufacturers also usually have their own printing management software, you probably ought to look at that first.